# Python argparse: optional positional argument without dash(es)?

Tags: command-line, python, arguments, python-3.x

Admittedly, Python's `argparse` is a versatile and powerful beast. But even after rereading the official docs, as well as many Q&As about `argparse` across the SE sites, I'm still unsure if this isn't possible or if I just lack the finer points og `argparse`.

For a tool `tool` with many subcommands (such as `abc` and `def`) I would like to implement subcommand-related help, preferably in the form of `tool abc help`, `tool def help`, and so on. However, these subcommands usually have positional arguments, such as `tool abc FOO` and `tool def FOO BAR`, with `FOO` and `BAR` being metavariables for which the CLI user needs to supply concrete values. `abc` and `def` are verbatim commands or "optional positional arguments" (if they may be called such at all).

Is there something like an optional command? Is this possible at all?

Comment: by "here on SO", you appear to have missed and landed at U&L. I've voted to migrate the question to SO.

Comment: have to admit that I use SO as a catch-all for all sites, you got me! I'm not sure if SO or U&L would be more fit...?

Comment: It's more suited for StackOverflow. It will be migrated eventually.